# Fail to run the exectuable via cmd or Python

Tags: python, cmd, executable

My tutor sent me an executable to run the simulation. The usage is to put the executable,  settings files and initial files to the same folder and double click the executable, and the executable will generate the result text file.

Recently I try to integrate this function into my python script. The goal is when I run the python script, the script could generate the basic input file in the folder and then run the executable to generate the result. A part of the script looks like this:

```
path_exe = r"D:\direction\xxx.exe"
subprocess.run(path_exe,shell=True)
```

However, it returns:

```
ERROR LOADING Keyfile_0 FILE
```

I'm sure that the "keyfile" is in the same direction, because it works well when I double click the executable.

Then I try to run it via `cmd`. I drag the executable into cmd window and press `enter`, the same error happens.

I don't know if it is blamed on the executable, or is the code error.

Comment: Try using the `cwd=` option.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: code doesn't have to run in folder which you expect. You should check `Current Working Directory` using `print( os.getcwd() )`. If it different than you expect then you can try to change it `os.chdir(expected_folder)` or you may try to use `subprocess.run(..., cwd=expected_folder)`

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm sorry but `ERROR LOADING Keyfile_0 FILE` is the full error reminder.  And I use `os.chdir(folder)` and then `subprocess.run(...)`, it works. Thanks!